# Can I get direct s3 url for a file uploaded with filepicker.io?

Tags: filepicker.io

I need filepicker.io to upload files to my s3 bucket and then just refer to those files directly in s3 without going through filepicker.io everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the S3 key in a number of ways, either as the .key property on the FPFile that is returned, or using the `filepicker.stat` call.